# Delay ajax call on key input in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am building an auto-complete like script for text inputs.
In order to avoid multiple unnecessary ajax calls, I would like to initiate ajax calls only after the user stopped typing text for 1 second. That way I will save some overhead calls for every key pressed. How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Thanks,

Joel

Comment: either for reference, or so you dont reinvent the wheel, jqueryui's autocomplete plugin is excellent, and has this exact feature (it is of course optional, and when in use, you can set the delay)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [debounce](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/) plugin or the - better-documented - [doTimeout](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/debouncing/) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this. I wasn't playing with above yet. Just using plain js.

```
var keyUpTime = 1000; // 1 sec
var keyUpTimeout = null;
$('input[type=text]').keyup( function(e) {
    clearTimeout(keyUpTimeout);
    keyUpTimeout = setTimeout(function() { sendAjax(); }, keyUpTime);
});
function sendAjax() {
    alert('Send it!');
}
```

Comment: You are polluting the global scope with `keyUpTime` and `keyUpTimeout`

Comment: Key events won't trigger if you right-click and select Paste in the context menu.

Answer (score 2):

There is another jquery plugin for this. It works fine for me [a link](http://narf.pl/jquery-typing/)